# Wordpress select metabox: Set an ID/CLASS for each option

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I created a select metabox within my functions.php on Wordpress.

```
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'CMS Logo',
        'id' => 'cms_icon_image',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'Wordpress'   => 'Wordpress',
            'Magento'     => 'Magento',
            'OpenCart'    => 'OpenCart',
        )
    )               
)
```

I need to set an unique ID or Class for each select option. This will help to style each option( I will add an image with css for each option)

Comment: You could use the key or value from the **options** array to define the class

Comment: @Lodder Can you please give me some details because i can't get the idea

Comment: I'm just getting an example ready with your code, will post it when it's finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is something you're looking for:

```
<?php
$array = array(
        'name' => 'CMS Logo',
        'id' => 'cms_icon_image',
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => array(
            'Wordpress'   => 'Wordpress',
            'Magento'     => 'Magento',
            'OpenCart'    => 'OpenCart',
        )
    ) ;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[] = $key;

    if (is_array($array[$key])) {
        $results = array_keys($array[$key]);
        echo "<select>";
        foreach ($results as $result => $val){
            echo "<option class='" . $val . "'>" . $val . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
}
?>
```

This will output a select box with an `<option>` for each option defined in the array.

Hope this helps